# Get host name/ip for Docker network

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have this:

```
# create network
docker network create cdt-net
```

how can I get the local IP/hostname for this Docker network "cdt-net"?

Using `docker network inspect cdt-net`, I get:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "cdt-net",
        "Id": "0c2bd01e2192a82fc5472e28b966b3692720ab902bfa99e8d4c6c825a13f8f11",
        "Created": "2017-05-09T23:33:52.632492853Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Containers": {
            "0f9dd64a2aafc95bdb9ea8cdbb2ab136d492426b421ee56780175d5710de5d32": {
                "Name": "cdt-selenium",
                "EndpointID": "ad5348e3fa445d241e0acec094c09f75c40ee8d0edcbe988f7ecbe43fb183c4a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "3c4d5394b42e444f313c3a8d2743e7564abfd65df66bf76cc22c676ca8e94861": {
                "Name": "cdt-mongo",
                "EndpointID": "5aa64d19e4eb429606b46826e616b391a27aebe794d8c945ef0af17ab34c3e57",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c9d0f5f1e5dbbe0be309ac0fa4b1620aca0b32e12b5f50027df541d6a519332b": {
                "Name": "cdt-server",
                "EndpointID": "7dbebd7e58c4c6579ebd0fcef54a86f22ae4696864fc783d3fcc9d953c949397",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

but from that, I still am not certain how I could access one of the containers by IP from outside the container. Is that possible?

Comment: `docker network inspect cdt-net` ?

Comment: yeah thanks, but for some reason, none of those IP addresses seem available

Comment: Available for...what?

Comment: well, I have a webserver running in that container, I want to be able to access the webserver from a web browser running on the machine that is hosting the container! At the moment, I just figure it's a matter of finding the right address.

Comment: Did you expose a port when you ran the container? That's common mistake number 1. Also more info on networking in case you missed it: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

Comment: Like @ManoMarks said, you need to do `-p <host-port>:<container-port>` as part of your `docker run ...` command. You will then be able to hit the container on `localhost:<host-port>`.

Comment: do you `cat /etc/hosts` about one of the containers in the network? What's inside?